# How to create Activemq http listener using java

Tags: java, spring, activemq-classic, resttemplate

I have used following code to read activemq message. I need to implement activemq listener using REST.

This is message read demo class

```
public class ActiveMQConsumer {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
         String url = "http://localhost:8161/api/message?destination=queue://test.queue&readTimeout=10000&type=queue&clientId=test";

         RestClient client = new RestClient(userName, password);
         String activeMQResponse = client.get(url);
         System.out.println(activeMQResponse);
     }
}
```

This is spring resttemplate HTTP connecting class

```
public class RestClient {

    private String server = "";
    private RestTemplate rest;
    private HttpHeaders headers;
    private HttpStatus status;

    public RestClient(String userName, String password) {
        this.rest = new RestTemplate();
        this.headers = createHeaders(userName, password);
    }

    public HttpHeaders createHeaders(String username, String password) {
        return new HttpHeaders() {
            {
                String auth = username + ":" + password;
                byte[] encodedAuth = Base64.encodeBase64(auth.getBytes(Charset.forName("US-ASCII")));
                String authHeader = "Basic " + new String(encodedAuth);
                set("Authorization", authHeader);
                set("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8");
                set("Accept", "*/*");
            }
        };
    }

    public String get(String uri) {
        HttpEntity<String> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<String>("", headers);
        ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity = rest.exchange(server + uri, HttpMethod.GET, requestEntity, String.class);
        this.setStatus(responseEntity.getStatusCode());
        return responseEntity.getBody();
    }   

    public HttpStatus getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(HttpStatus status) {
        this.status = status;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I wouldn't use RestClient for contacting some broker, since it's not just simple http communication. It's `mqtt` or `amqt` protocol not `http`. Ok I see that active mq provides http api, but still, I suggest to go with different approach.

Use [apache-camel](http://camel.apache.org/activemq.html) activemq component. Then
you will simply create a route like:

```
from("activemq:queue:your_queue")
  .process(e -> {...}) // your processing of message goes here.
```

More about how to create routes can be found [here](http://camel.apache.org/routes.html). Good thing is, that camel has great support and also great documentation.

If it is an requirement, that you **must** consume messages from rest, then i would probably use [unirest](http://unirest.io/).